# rack-cors rails api only accept JSON requests from a statically served site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, reactjs

I'm building a react app that gets it JSON from a rails API. The API currently has rack-cors installed(which works great! can make the calls I want from the react app) I would like it so that the API will listen for requests only from the react app.

Here's the pertinent code from my `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

I'm currently running my rails server on port 4000 and running my react app on port 3000. I've tried changing the argument for origins from `"*"` to `localhost:3000` but I'm still getting successful post requests from Chrome's Postman REST client. In production, I only want updates to my rails API from the react client and nothing else, so I'd like to emulate locally first. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird thing. I changed my origin to `localhost:2000` and the react requests broke. great! But the postman request was still successful... I'm guessing that means postman always is able to know the origin? Confusing